# Изменить цвет кпопки ActionBar

Tags: actionbar, android

Имею `ActionBar`, цвет которого совпадает с цветом нажатой кнопки `home`, и нажатие незаметно!

Как изменить цвет кнопки Actionbar?

Comment: c API 14 можно поменять
`<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/btn</item>`
`<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/btn</item>`

Comment: @monomi пробовал, но интересует <14

Comment: @katso тогда предположу что это можно сделать лишь кастомным `ActionBar`

Answer (score 1):

Напишите xml файл с тегом selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" /> 
</selector>
```

причем, в `android:drawable=""` вы можете запихнуть как картинку так и цвет.

и файл селектора должен находиться в папке `\project_name\res\drawable`.

затем ссылаетесь на этот селектор либо в коде, либо в описании макета.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как применить этот селектор к кнопкам экшнбара

Answer (score 0):

[`Selectors drawables`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Так же, вы можете переопределить `android:actionBarItemBackground` в используемой теме.

Comment: Эт понятно, как это применить к кнопкам Экшнбара?